# How to open documents like ppt, excel etc in separate installed app in iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am working in xamarin.ios. In my app I need to show some documents like ppt, excel etc. I want to open these files in separate installed app in device that supports these files. Means if I try to open a excel file, then I can get list of all the installed app that support to open this file and the app that I select, opens the document.

How I can achieve it in xamarin.ios?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will ask you which app you want to open in:

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("filepath or http url"));
```

You need a application on your phone that can open this special files.

Same question can be found here: [Xamarin Forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/103042/how-to-open-pdf-or-txt-file-in-default-app-on-xamarin-forms)

Comment: I think it is used in xamarin forms. I need for xamarin.ios.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `UIDocumentInteractionController`:

```
documentInteraction = new UIDocumentInteractionController();
documentInteraction.Url = new NSUrl(NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("myExcel", "xlsx"), false);

documentInteraction.PresentOptionsMenu(sender.Bounds, sender, true);
```

Make sure retain this `documentInteraction` as a property. And the third party app which you want to open this file must support the opening method.

Moreover you can use this controller to preview files in-app:

```
// Add a delegate
documentInteraction.Delegate = new MyDocumentDelegate(this);

public class MyDocumentDelegate : UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate
{
    UIViewController presentedViewController;

    public MyDocumentDelegate(UIViewController viewController)
    {
        presentedViewController = viewController;
    }

    public override UIViewController ViewControllerForPreview(UIDocumentInteractionController controller)
    {
        return presentedViewController;
    }
}
```

Comment: Then can we close this post? It can help other community understand how to use UIDocumentInteractionController.